# Efficiently drawing from non-parametrically estimated distribution

Tags: monte-carlo, integral

Suppose I can estimate a distribution $G(x)$ as

$$ \hat G(x) = f(x, X)$$

where $X$ are my data points and $f$ is a known, but computationally heavy function.

Eventually I'm interested in

$$ h(\theta) = \int k(x, \theta) dG(x)$$

which I will have to evaluate many many times for different $\theta$. Thus, sampling from $G(x)$ repeatedly is very slow, since it involves repeated evaluation of $f(x,X)$.

I'm thinking about pre-evaluating $\hat G(x)$ at a set of pre-determined points, e.g., some grid, and only sampling from there, but I'm worried that this might bias my results.

What can be done here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about this as a numerical integration problem, you can refer to the extremely large literature on same.  As a starting point, if $k(\theta,x)dG(x)$ can be reasonably well approximated by some high degree polynomial, [Gaussian quadrature](https://coast.nd.edu/jjwteach/www/www/30125/pdfnotes/lecture16_19v17.pdf) may work very well with relatively few sample points required, e.g., 11 points will get you an exact integral for a 23-degree polynomial.  Since those points would remain the same for different values of $\theta$, you could indeed pre-compute $G$ at the appropriate values of $x$.  There are plenty of other quadrature and adaptive formulae that may be more-or-less efficient depending on the shape of $k(\theta, x)dG(x)$ over the range of $x$.

Note that different numerical integration formulae have different requirements for the range of $x$; these are usually satisfied by finding a transform of the original $x$ to a new variable that lies within the range and doesn't have unfortunate behavior within the range (e.g., virtually all the mass in the range $[-1,1]$ is concentrated between $[-0.005,-0.0049]$.)  Finding such an integration rule and associated transform is the art of numerical integration, which we can't get more into here since I have no idea what your function looks like.  However, off-the-shelf methods work well in most practical applications, so it may not be much of an issue for you.

Answer (score -2):

Use a low-discrepancy sequence in your pre-computation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence